# Conditional format based on position of character within a word - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to determine if it's possible to use conditional formatting on specific characters in a word and their position within the word? For example, when marking a spelling test. If a student spells the word 'bed', can I format a cell showing the 'b' is in the correct position? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do (ie. tick the boxes if the letters are in the correct position):

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking it could potentially something like this: =IF(MID(B7,1,1)=b,"TRUE","FALSE") (when the spelling word is spelt in B7, the 'b' box where the formula is inserted will tick if TRUE). However, this isn't working and I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, this is not possible in google sheets within the scope of conditional formatting. only whole cell can be conditionally formatted when compared against something